# Percentage difference between two values

Tags: javascript

I am using the following simple JavaScript code to calculate the percentage difference between two values:

```
subOBS001 = (vars.obs001acount) - (vars.obs001asent); 
divOBS001 = (subOBS001) / (vars.obs001asent); 
modOBS001 = (divOBS001) * (100);

if (modOBS > 30) {%> <%= modOBS %><span id="greenStatus">&#8226;</span> <%} else {%> <%= modOBS %>
```

Is there a simpler way to perform my calculation? Have it all in one single line using parenthesis?

Comment: `%> <%= modOBS %>`... that doesn't look like simple JS code to me!

Comment: JScript + Classic ASP?

Comment: This is a phantomjs which is a js interpreter used in crm tools, the '<%' tag is to let the tool know this is a js code block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculation done on one line, if that is what you want:

```
modOBS001 = (vars.obs001acount - vars.obs001asent) / vars.obs001asent * 100;
```

And if your math is correct and you want the value of `vars.obs001asent` represent 100%.

Comment: And in which world can you divide by zero?

Comment: @Azarus in a world where it doesn't matter.

Comment: In case your previous value is 0 you would be dividing by zero.. and that would result in a error.